# throws “Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException” when compiling

Tags: c#, msbuild, stack-overflow

I've got an error in only one project when compiling. I already check every classes and cannot find recursive in classes.

I can't fix the problem. I think you can check file of Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets, and may be you can fix the problem. I make project in VS2017, and i can run. Now, I use VS2019 but i can't build the project.

Error:

```
1>------ Derleme başladı: Proje: Flight.Utility, Yapılandırma: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error : 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error : Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

Someone can help to me ?

Thank you.

Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c)  Microsoft.  All Rights Reserved.  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.  See License.txt in the project root for license information. -->
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets"/>

  <Target Name="CoreCompile"
          Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);
                  @(Compile);
                  @(_CoreCompileResourceInputs);
                  $(ApplicationIcon);
                  $(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile);
                  @(ReferencePathWithRefAssemblies);
                  @(CompiledLicenseFile);
                  @(LinkResource);
                  @(EmbeddedDocumentation);
                  $(Win32Resource);
                  $(Win32Manifest);
                  @(CustomAdditionalCompileInputs);
                  $(ResolvedCodeAnalysisRuleSet);
                  @(AdditionalFiles);
                  @(EmbeddedFiles);
                  @(EditorConfigFiles)"
          Outputs="@(DocFileItem);
                   @(IntermediateAssembly);
                   @(IntermediateRefAssembly);
                   @(_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath);
                   $(NonExistentFile);
                   @(CustomAdditionalCompileOutputs)"
          Returns="@(CscCommandLineArgs)"
          DependsOnTargets="$(CoreCompileDependsOn);_BeforeVBCSCoreCompile">
    <!-- These two compiler warnings are raised when a reference is bound to a different version
             than specified in the assembly reference version number.  MSBuild raises the same warning in this case,
             so the compiler warning would be redundant. -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' != 'v1.0') and ('$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' != 'v1.1')">
      <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1701;1702</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- To match historical behavior, when inside VS11+ disable the warning from csc.exe indicating that no sources were passed in-->
      <NoWarn Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' AND '$(VisualStudioVersion)' != '' AND '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &gt; '10.0'">$(NoWarn);2008</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- If the user has specified AppConfigForCompiler, we'll use it. If they have not, but they set UseAppConfigForCompiler,
                 then we'll use AppConfig -->
      <AppConfigForCompiler Condition="'$(AppConfigForCompiler)' == '' AND '$(UseAppConfigForCompiler)' == 'true'">$(AppConfig)</AppConfigForCompiler>

      <!-- If we are targeting winmdobj we want to specifically the pdbFile property since we do not want it to collide with the output of winmdexp-->
      <PdbFile Condition="'$(PdbFile)' == '' AND '$(OutputType)' == 'winmdobj' AND '$(_DebugSymbolsProduced)' == 'true'">$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName).compile.pdb</PdbFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <LangVersion Condition="'$(LangVersion)' == '' AND
        (('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' AND '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.0') OR
         ('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETStandard' AND '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v2.1'))">preview</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Condition is to filter out the _CoreCompileResourceInputs so that it doesn't pass in culture resources to the compiler -->
    <Csc Condition="'%(_CoreCompileResourceInputs.WithCulture)' != 'true'"
         AdditionalLibPaths="$(AdditionalLibPaths)"
         AddModules="@(AddModules)"
         AdditionalFiles="@(AdditionalFiles)"
         AllowUnsafeBlocks="$(AllowUnsafeBlocks)"
         AnalyzerConfigFiles="@(EditorConfigFiles)"
         Analyzers="@(Analyzer)"
         ApplicationConfiguration="$(AppConfigForCompiler)"
         BaseAddress="$(BaseAddress)"
         CheckForOverflowUnderflow="$(CheckForOverflowUnderflow)"
         ChecksumAlgorithm="$(ChecksumAlgorithm)"
         CodeAnalysisRuleSet="$(ResolvedCodeAnalysisRuleSet)"
         CodePage="$(CodePage)"
         DebugType="$(DebugType)"
         DefineConstants="$(DefineConstants)"
         DelaySign="$(DelaySign)"
         DisabledWarnings="$(NoWarn)"
         DisableSdkPath="$(DisableSdkPath)"
         DocumentationFile="@(DocFileItem)"
         EmbedAllSources="$(EmbedAllSources)"
         EmbeddedFiles="@(EmbeddedFiles)"
         EmitDebugInformation="$(DebugSymbols)"
         EnvironmentVariables="$(CscEnvironment)"
         ErrorEndLocation="$(ErrorEndLocation)"
         ErrorLog="$(ErrorLog)"
         ErrorReport="$(ErrorReport)"
         Features="$(Features)"
         FileAlignment="$(FileAlignment)"
         GenerateFullPaths="$(GenerateFullPaths)"
         HighEntropyVA="$(HighEntropyVA)"
         Instrument="$(Instrument)"
         KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)"
         KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)"
         LangVersion="$(LangVersion)"
         LinkResources="@(LinkResource)"
         MainEntryPoint="$(StartupObject)"
         ModuleAssemblyName="$(ModuleAssemblyName)"
         NoConfig="true"
         NoLogo="$(NoLogo)"
         NoStandardLib="$(NoCompilerStandardLib)"
         NoWin32Manifest="$(NoWin32Manifest)"
         Nullable="$(Nullable)"
         Optimize="$(Optimize)"
         Deterministic="$(Deterministic)"
         PublicSign="$(PublicSign)"
         OutputAssembly="@(IntermediateAssembly)"
         OutputRefAssembly="@(IntermediateRefAssembly)"
         PdbFile="$(PdbFile)"
         Platform="$(PlatformTarget)"
         Prefer32Bit="$(Prefer32Bit)"
         PreferredUILang="$(PreferredUILang)"
         ProvideCommandLineArgs="$(ProvideCommandLineArgs)"
         References="@(ReferencePathWithRefAssemblies)"
         RefOnly="$(ProduceOnlyReferenceAssembly)"
         ReportAnalyzer="$(ReportAnalyzer)"
         Resources="@(_CoreCompileResourceInputs);@(CompiledLicenseFile)"
         ResponseFiles="$(CompilerResponseFile)"
         RuntimeMetadataVersion="$(RuntimeMetadataVersion)"
         SharedCompilationId="$(SharedCompilationId)"
         SkipCompilerExecution="$(SkipCompilerExecution)"
         Sources="@(Compile)"
         SubsystemVersion="$(SubsystemVersion)"
         TargetType="$(OutputType)"
         ToolExe="$(CscToolExe)"
         ToolPath="$(CscToolPath)"
         TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(TreatWarningsAsErrors)"
         UseHostCompilerIfAvailable="$(UseHostCompilerIfAvailable)"
         UseSharedCompilation="$(UseSharedCompilation)"
         Utf8Output="$(Utf8Output)"
         VsSessionGuid="$(VsSessionGuid)"
         WarningLevel="$(WarningLevel)"
         WarningsAsErrors="$(WarningsAsErrors)"
         WarningsNotAsErrors="$(WarningsNotAsErrors)"
         Win32Icon="$(ApplicationIcon)"
         Win32Manifest="$(Win32Manifest)"
         Win32Resource="$(Win32Resource)"
         PathMap="$(PathMap)"
         SourceLink="$(SourceLink)">
      <Output TaskParameter="CommandLineArgs" ItemName="CscCommandLineArgs" />
    </Csc>

    <ItemGroup>
      <_CoreCompileResourceInputs Remove="@(_CoreCompileResourceInputs)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)" Condition="'$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != ''" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you post your csproj file?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with project configuration, it is the compiler that keels over while trying to compile the code you wrote.  Technically possible, the C# compiler use a recursive decent parser. Narrow down to the specific section of code that trips the problem by focusing on the changes you made recently, as shown by source control, and commenting out chunks of code until the problem disappears.

Comment: I had a similar issue, solved it by updating Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem only in VS 2019. In VS 2017 everything worked fine. In my case the problem was occurred because of my Fluent API, the call chain was too long (about 400 lines of codes). When I split the call chain into small parts it started working.

I don't know why this happened, probably some problem with the code parser in VS 2019.

Comment: imazing. my problem solved with your solution too. i didn`t expect work.